# Listing / Adding / Deleting Members from a (legacy) Google Group

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm part of an organization that created and still actively uses a Google Group. When Google started it's G-Suite service for organizations, got on board with having a proper Google organization. The problem is, now when members join and leave the organization, there's this nuisance task that requires someone to add them or remove them from the legacy Google Group.

That group, as far as I can tell, is dissociated with the G-suite organization. We do have an Administrator account (from the G-suite organization) among the Managers of the Google Group, FWIW. The Google Group has an email address that ends "@googlegroups.com".

So I tried using [this Google tool](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/get) to just examine the Google Group using the aforementioned Administrator account from G-Suite, and it just gives back a 404 with this response body:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Domain not found."
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Domain not found."
 }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do (automate the aforementioned nuisance task).

Ultimately, I think [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members) is the set of APIs that I will need to use, and I've tested very basically that they work for a Google Group that is actually part of the G-Suite organization (i.e. has the same email domain).

Answer (score 0):

I chatted to Google support and the word I got was basically, no dice. Legacy / free Google Groups are, from what I understand, not supported for API access.